# What is delegation in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, delegation

I came across this in my textbook, but I don't even know what delegation is. I know what inclusion is, but not what delegation is.

> In the context of Ruby, compare delegation to module inclusion in
>   terms of the notion of class interfaces.
>
> With module inclusion, methods defined in modules become part of the
>   interface of classes(and all their subclasses). This is not the case
>   with delegations.

Can you explain in layman's terms?

Comment: Here's a decent explanation with examples: http://khelll.com/blog/ruby/delegation-in-ruby/

Comment: So math.sqrt(10) is delegation and include math sqrt(10) is include?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delegation is, simply put, is when one object uses another object for a method's invocation.

If you have something like this:

```
class A
  def foo
    puts "foo"
  end
end

class B
  def initialize
    @a = A.new
  end

  def bar
    puts "bar"
  end

  def foo
    @a.foo
  end
end
```

An instance of the B class will utilize the A class's `foo` method when its `foo` method is called. The instance of `B` delegates the `foo` method to the `A` class, in other words.

Answer (score 2):

```
class A
  def answer_to(q)
    "here is the A's answer to question: #{q}"
  end
end

class B
  def initialize(a)
    @a = a
  end
  def answer_to(q)
    @a.answer_to q
  end
end

b = B.new(A.new)

p b.answer_to("Q?")


module AA
  def answer_to(q)
    "here is the AA's answer to question: #{q}"
  end
end

class BB
  include AA
end

p BB.new.answer_to("Q?")
```

`B` delegate the question to `A`, while `BB` use module `AA` to answer question.

Comment: I got this:"here is the A's answer to question: Q?"
"here is the A's answer to question: Q?" shouldn't it be: "here is the A's answer to question: Q?"
"here is the AA's answer to question: Q?"

Comment: @OnTheFly , sorry I make a mistake. and thanks for your reply.
the problem is `B` will use its own `answer_to`, not the one in `AA`.